# Is there a way to use video files from other sources on iMovie on iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ipad, ios, iphone, imovie

I have been given an assignment to create a video in school and I would just like to know if and how you go about getting movies not recorded on the iDevice into the camera roll and then into iMovie. I have tried everything I can think of but I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

This is a total guess, but when you get photos in emails and on the web in safari, you can save them and they appear in your camera roll.

Could the same trick be used to save movies?

Comment: I think this may work in principle, but in practice the video files are too large to send by email unfortunately. Thanks anyway, guess I'll keep searching!